# Linq To Entity: delete a row

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I want delete a row in the database using linq to entity.
I have:

```
using (SIEntities siContext = new SIEntities())
{
     //linq query to find object to delete

   siContext.MyEntities.DeleteObject(myobject);
}
```

Anyway the methos DeleteObject doesn't exist (as Delete()).
I've tried also siContext.DeleteObject() and siContext.Delete() but don't find that method.
Missing some namespaces?
How can i delete the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `Remove` method:

> **`DbSet<TEntity>.Remove` Method**
>
> Marks the given entity as Deleted such that it will be deleted from
>   the database when SaveChanges is called. Note that the entity must
>   exist in the context in some other state before this method is called.

Comment: OK!! siContext is derived by DBContext so i must use Remove() and not DeleteObject()